# Split multi-line cell into columns using data prefix as column heading

Tags: excel

I have cells with multiple lines e.g.

| Column |
| --- |
| Name: J Smith Address: 123 Main St Phone: 14380 |

Now, using the "Text to Columns" button I can split the rows into separate columns. So far so good.

However, my problem is that some cells don't have data on every row. For example:

| Column |
| --- |
| Name: J Smith Address: 123 Main St Phone: 14380 |
| Address: 3 Green St Phone: 54778 |

When I split the above, I get misaligned columns like so:

| Column | Column | Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name: J Smith | Address: 123 Main St | Phone: 14380 |
| Address: 3 Green St | Phone: 54778 |  |

Is there a way to make the columns aligned, so that all the 'name' values are in the same column, all address values in the same column etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `FILTERXML()` with ***starts-with*** or ***contains*** argument. try-

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(., 'Name')]"),"")
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(., 'Address')]"),"")
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(., 'Phone')]"),"")
```

For details about `FILTERXML()` read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/5514747) from JvdV.

[image]

Comment: `FILTERXML()` is the best function and better choice =)